# How to start new Activity from Integrated google api Activity

Tags: android

I try to integrate google api in my mainactivity and also want to open new activity named UserActivity which should display UserName and UserEmail. How can I do that? Please give some suggestions or demo codes.

Comment: Please ask a better question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

no difference. the handy`startActivity()` does the job. just use it wherever you need it.